# How to make sudo use a separate password?

Tags: password, sudo, users, authentication

Using Ubuntu 14.04, I have 2 accounts:

- Account A (first one set up) with Password 1
- Account B (second set up) with Password 2, when updating software in Account B, I use Password 1 to authenticate.  Has been successful so far.

How do I set up sudo with its own Password, and then run `sudo apt-get clean`?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to set up a universal password that all users would have to input in order to execute a command as root with a `sudo` command.

Example:

- Account-**A** = Password-**1**
- Account-**B** = Password-**2**
- root          = root-password

If Account-**A** *or* Account-**B** enters the command:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Then the subsequent output:

```
[sudo] password for root:
```

would be the same for both users.

This is typically **NOT** the preferred method of security through the use of sudo as implemented by Ubuntu.

**This is not the *recommended* method of password implementation**

For security reasons, Ubuntu does not enable a root user account. Unlike Debian, Ubuntu disables the root account.

**You have been Warned this is not recommended!**

Here's how it's done:

**First,** open a terminal and type the following command to set up a root password:

```
sudo passwd root
```

You will be prompted for your user-password to execute sudo. You will then be prompted to choose a password for root. You will then be prompted to re-enter the newly chosen password for root.

**Next**, change the default editor to nano instead of vi with this command:

```
sudo select-editor
```

You will be asked to choose an editor. Type the number that corresponds to "/bin/nano" and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

**Then,** execute the following command to edit your sudoers file. **You must use the `visudo` command to edit the /etc/sudoers file.** Do **NOT** edit this file using gedit, do **NOT** use vi, **DON'T** use nano or leafpad or any other text editor because you risk locking yourself out of the sudo command completely for all users if there is a synatax error. Using `visudo` will fix syntax errors or alert you without saving the changes.

```
sudo visudo
```

Scroll down to the first line that begins with the word **"Defaults"** and press enter. Move up to the newly created blank line and insert the following line:

```
Defaults        rootpw
```

**Use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key between the two words and do not use spaces!!**

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> to write out the changes to the file. When asked to save the file as **"/etc/sudoers.tmp"**, delete **".tmp"** and press <kbd>enter</kbd> to save the file as **"/etc/sudoers"** instead.

You will now be prompted for the root password whenever any user executes a command with `sudo`.

Refrences:

[wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo)

[how-do-i-make-sudo-ask-for-the-root-password](https://superuser.com/questions/161593/how-do-i-make-sudo-ask-for-the-root-password)

[set-sudo-password-differently-from-login-one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94626/set-sudo-password-differently-from-login-one)

[Debian documents "sudo_configuration"](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch01.en.html#_sudo_configuration)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)

[wiki.debian.org/sudo](https://wiki.debian.org/sudo)

Comment: Also, I found the answer to this post quite helpful http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68669/how-to-add-self-to-sudoers-list